# Sum the positive elements of an array using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, recursion, sum

I'm learning recursion and trying to calculate the sum of the positive elements of an array but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int sum (int arr[],int n)
{
    if(n==-1)
    return  0;
    /*else if(arr[n]<0)
    return arr[n]+sum(arr,n+1) ;*/
    else
    return arr[n-1]+sum(arr , n-1);
        
}
    
int main()
{
    int  n , arr[n] ;
    cout<<"give the value of  n : " ; cin>>n;
    cout<<"give the values of the array ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
    cout<<"the value of positive elements is  : " << sum(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your problem is, read [ask] for further info. As a new user, also take the [tour]. BTW: It can be helpful if you hard-code the values instead of manually inputting them, it allows for easier testing with one less error source.

Comment: In the first line of main, what is the value of n? how large is arr?

Comment: As well as the other errors, in `sum` if `n` is 0 then you go into the else clause and end up accessing `arr[-1]` which is unlikely what you want.

Comment: Even if you're using the compiler extension to enable variable-length arrays in C++, declaring `int arr[n];` before you've initialized `n` with anything isn't going to work. It needs to allocate memory for `arr` when it's declared, not retroactively after you've assigned a value to `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. in C++ (specially starting from C++11) avoid, when possible, old C-style arrays; use `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::array` (starting from C++11) instead;
2. When possible, write generic code using templates; in this case, avoid a `sum()` function that works only with C-style arrays but write a template function that can works also with `std::vector`, etc.
3. When you manage sizes, use unsigned integers (`std::size_t`, for example), not signed integers; this to be consistent with the standard C++ library and avoid a lot of signed/unsigned inconsistencies.

Given that you're learning recursion, I propose the following `sum()` function

```
template <typename T>
int sum (T const & arr, std::size_t n)
 {
   return   ( arr[n] > 0 ? arr[n]        : 0)
          + (      n > 0 ? sum(arr, n-1) : 0);
 }
```

Observe the first row, where

```
( arr[n] > 0 ? arr[n]        : 0)
```

`arr[n]` is added to the sum iff (if and only if) is greater than zero (otherwise is added zero)

Observe also the second row, where

```
+ (      n > 0 ? sum(arr, n-1) : 0);
```

the recursion continue (`sum(arr, n-1)` is added) iff `n` is greater than zero.

The following is a full compiling example that uses `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int sum (T const & arr, std::size_t n)
 {
   return   ( arr[n] > 0 ? arr[n]        : 0)
          + (      n > 0 ? sum(arr, n-1) : 0);
 }

int main()
 {
   std::size_t      dim;
   std::vector<int> vec;

   std::cout << "give the value of  n : " ; std::cin >> dim;
   std::cout << "give the values of the array ";

   vec.resize(dim);

   for ( auto & val : vec )
      std::cin >> val;

  
   std::cout << "the value of positive elements is  : " 
      << (dim > 0u ? sum(vec, dim-1u) : 0) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: i'm new to this languange but thanks really thanks for your advices !!

Comment: @AdrianMole - D'Oh! Horrible error. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @WalidWalid - There was an horrible error in my code (see Adrian Mole comment); corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function should return one of three values:

1. If we've reached the end of the array, return zero
2. Else, if the 'current' array element is negative or zero, return the 'next' recursion
3. Else, if the 'current' element is positive, return the **sum** of that and the next recursion.

On each recursive call, we need to: (a) Increment the index for the 'current' element; and (b) reduce the number of elements left in the array. For (a), we can make use of the fact that an array passed as a function parameter *decays to a pointer to its first element*, so we can just add one to that pointer for the recursive call:

```cpp
int sum(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) return 0; // Reached the end of the array: return zero
    if (*arr <= 0) return sum(arr + 1, n - 1); // Non-positive number: skip it
    return sum(arr + 1, n - 1) + *arr;  // Add this number to the recursion result!
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

---

EDIT: Also, if you insist on using variable length arrays (VLAs - not standard C++), then you need to declare `int arr[n]` ***after*** you have read the value of `n` given by the user. But I would recommend using a fixed (maximum) size, like: `int n, arr[100];`.

Comment: You can save an else.

Comment: @Surt Indeed (see edit). I was stuck between two styles: using `else` for second and third case (for clarity) or not using it at all. I have now made consistent non-use of the `else`.

Comment: hello ! 
your answer worked as well but in some cases like when i chose 2 as an array lenght doesnt work do you know anything about this errore

Comment: @WalidWalid I can't reproduce your error with an array length of 2 (or even 1). Did you make the change(s) suggested in the last paragraph?

Comment: but if we fixed the size why we add n on the function's arguments!
note: if i fixed the size and change it after still the same probleme

Comment: @WalidWalid When you pass an array to a function, that function can't work out *for itself* how big the array is ... unless you tell it! That's why we pass the `n` parameter, and why we decrease it by one for each recursive call (the 'remaining' array is smaller for each of those calls).

Answer (score -1):

> ... learning recursion and trying to calculate the sum of the positive elements of an array ...

Consider what to do if there was only 1 element in the array and then code for that.
`return (arr[0] > 0) ? arr[0] : 0;`

Else break the problem down into a smaller sub-problem.

Others have answered *how*, yet use recursion is an iterative way -- only decrementing the array size.  The recursion depth could be `O(n)`.

I recommend to divide the size of the problem by two.
This alternative uses a far smaller depth: `O(log n)`.

```
int sum (const int arr[], int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return (n > 0 && arr[0] > 0) ? arr[0] : 0;
  }
  int left_size = n/2;
  return sum(arr, left_size) + sum(arr + left_size, n - left_size);
}
```